# How to store a numpy array with shape (32,32) as (1,32,32)

Tags: python, numpy

For various reasons, I need to transfer a 2d numpy array of shape (32,32) to 3d shape (1,32,32). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`np.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html#numpy.ndarray.reshape):

```
>>> a = np.zeros((32, 32))
>>> a.reshape((1, 32, 32))
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        ..., 
        [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]]])
>>>
```

I used a array of zeros for demonstrating.